# Description перед ссылкой

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

На сайт добавил блок "Поделиться", воспользовавшись конструктором Яндекса tech.yandex.ru/share/.

Проблема в том, что дескрипшен ставится после ссылки [http://prntscr.com/c3shw3был](http://prntscr.com/c3shw3%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB), а нужно, чтобы перед ссылкой ставился http://prntscr.com/c2blix. Реально ли это?
Пример моего кода:

```
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte" data-size="s" id="vkontakte" data-description="дескрипшен" data-title="тайтл">Поделиться Вконтакте</div>
```

Comment: Не понятно. Что за редактор у вас на стриншотах и при чем здесь блок "поделиться"? Сформулируйте яснее, пожалуйста. А лучше - дайте рабочий пример. И поправьте ссылку в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт яндекса сам определяет, как лучше формировать текст для репостинга. Например, в твиттере он формирует текст по формуле `#{page_title} #{url}`.

Теоретически вы можете:

- Скачать скрипт [yastatic.net/share2/share.js](https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js)
- Найти в нем формулу формирования текста для вашего сайта/соцсети
- Изменить ее как вам хочется
- Подключать на сайте ваш измененный скрипт вместо скрипта яндекса

Но в этом случае вам придется следить за тем, чтобы скрипт был в актуальном состоянии, и обновлять его время от времени, выкачивая новую версию скрипта с сайта Яндекса и внося в нее все те же изменения.